# append query string to URL on event (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, query-string

my client has a website that currently makes requests on a particular event (click, load etc). the website is working well and all but he has a problem with getting the website statistics with Google Analytics, the reason is, because the website never does a re-direct to a different page, it is all within the same page and no matter what event is loaded in the website(be it a video, tables etc) everything are displayed under the same url

```
www.somewebsite.com/default.aspx
```

what I want to achieve is on a particular event, change the url to

```
www.somewebsite.com/default.aspx?type=abc&id=999
```

How can I do this,. what is the easiest method to do this? please advise. The whole website is built in C#.

Many Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to use the anchor (hash) after the url: default.aspx#type=bc&id=999.

Answer (score 1):

Is this event happening on the server or the client?

If it's on the server, you can call [`Response.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4.aspx) and add your new query string parameter to the current url.

If it's on the client (Javascript), you can set the `location` property.

Comment: Yep i tried that too, but when I do response.redirect, it loads the homepage again, because basically all I am doing is hiding and showing elements based on events, if i do a response.redirect, it will reload teh homepage. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve your page's state, try adding your querystring parameter to the form's `action` parameter in Javascript.

Alternatively, as jeffamaphone suggested, you can change the hash (the part after the `#` sign) by setting `location.hash` without posting back to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you should probably move some of the elements to different pages... this is based on what you said:

> because basically all I am doing is
>   hiding and showing elements based on
>   events, if i do a response.redirect,
>   it will reload teh homepage.

If I understand correctly, the user is never redirected to a different page, you are just hiding/unhiding elements from default.aspx based in query strings... correct? the simplest solution will be to split that content into different aspx pages.